# Make key value pair from two different array

Tags: javascript, json, object

**I'm using local storage to get an arrays of strings,**

First value `attrIds` is as follows,

```
var attrIds = localStorage.getItem('attributeids');
attrIds = JSON.parse(attrIds);
```

[image: Screenshot1]

Second value `confOptions` is as follows,

[image: Screenshot2]

I want something like this,

```
144: "5595"
93: "5487"
```

I have tried creating a loop inside the loop and tried to set the key and value but it's not working. I have also tried to set the single JSON object as key and setting value as '' but couldn't move further with that.

Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Comment: You want to map each value from the first array with every value of the second array from the same index?

Comment: yes as i mentioned in my question

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). `.getItem()` returns a string. `attrIds` and `confOptions` are both arrays of strings.

Answer (score 2):

#### Create a nested array and then use `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const 
  a = ["144", "93"],
  b = ["5595", "5487"],
  c = Object.fromEntries(a.map((v, i) => [v, b[i]]));

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop, you could do something like:

```
var attrIds = localStorage.getItem('attributeids');
attrIds = JSON.parse(attrIds);
confOptions = ["5595", "5487"]
const object = {};

for(let i=0; i<attrIds.length;i++)
object[attrIds[i]] = confOptions[i]
```

Comment: please add a full solution with for loop, really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a simple for loop, accessing the items from the arrays, and assigning properties to an empty object.

```js
const keys = ['144', '93'];
const values = ['5595', '5487'];

const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

console.log(obj); // prints { 144: '5595', 93: '5487' }
```